# @font-face chrome rendering

Tags: fonts, font-face

I was wondering if somebody else have had this problem - @font-face fonts are not rendering correctly in Chrome, well sometimes they do, sometimes don't, which is actually the problem because I can't track what's wrong on my own. In other browsers everything is fine. I am using Icomoon fonts and their syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    src:url('/fonts/entypo.eot');
    src:url('/fonts/entypo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/entypo.svg#entypo') format('svg'),
        url('/fonts/entypo.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/entypo.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Use the following CSS code if you want to use data attributes for inserting your icons */
[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* Use the following CSS code if you want to have a class per icon */
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    font-style: normal;
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height:1;
}
```

.htaccess in the fonts folder:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

root .htaccess has the same rules.

So I don't know what else can be wrong and is messing with my fonts.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122465) in Windows Chrome where it does not render Private Use Area unicode characters.

If you have `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` in your project, set `text-rendering: auto;` for the icons class and they should render in Windows Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that chrome has some issues with rendering fonts, at least with some rules, you can check this [post](https://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/15021/font-face-rendering-issue-in-chrome-for-pc/p1) for some tips how to improve you situation and this page from [typekit](http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/) to understand a bit better the process.

Bye

Comment: I think he might refer to another problem: Icomoon sometimes doesn't work on Chrome on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the same problems/bugs do tend to persist with Chrome...

This may be helpful for some. I was getting blank print preview and prints from Chrome with @font-face specified fonts, though other browsers worked perfectly.

Turns out it works fine when NOT served from localhost, but from my actual server.

Wish I tried that many, many hours ago.